# How to switch page without click <Link> in React?

Tags: reactjs

In some case I need to switch page without click anything.
 makes me click some btn, url and so on.
Also I don't want to reload a page.
Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you using a particular router? Assuming you're using the most common, react-router, this is duplicate of: [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `React-Router`.

You can switch page like this(if use React-Router):

```js
this.props.history.push('/index');
```

You should use `withRouter` if your component don't hava history in props.

```js
function Page(props) {
    function handleClick() {
        props.history.push('/index')
    }
    return (<p onClick={handleClick}>index page</p>)
}

export default withRouter(Page)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

```
// usually all you need
<Link to="/somewhere"/>

// but you can use a location instead
const location = {
  pathname: '/somewhere',
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
}

<Link to={location}/>
<Redirect to={location}/>
history.push(location)
history.replace(location)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router v4, you can do it like this it won't reload the page.

```
this.props.history.push('/foo')
```

For earlier versions

```
this.props.router.push('/foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using react's `navigate`:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate("/another-page")
```